# unable to select using nested query in where clause

Tags: mysql

First I want select some column from `bill_client` and one column form `bill_pkg` and that's simple like below:

**Query:**

```
SELECT c.company_id, c.client_id, p.pkg_rate
FROM bill_client c
JOIN bill_pkg p on c.pkg_id=p.pkg_id
WHERE c.status=1
```

I actually trying select with where `extract(year_month from curdate())>`

```
SELECT c.company_id, c.client_id, p.pkg_rate
FROM bill_client c
JOIN bill_pkg p on c.pkg_id=p.pkg_id
WHERE c.status=1 and extract(year_month from curdate())>
 (SELECT MAX(due_month)
 FROM bill_rent
 WHERE c.client_id=client_id and c.company_id=company_id
 GROUP BY client_id, company_id)
```

But this query return only those row where `client_id` are match with `bill_rent` table, not all row from `bill_client` table. I need check that `company_id` with the `client_id` exist yet `bill_rent` table `due_month` column for the current month. Any help please.

Here's the table schema:

tabll:**bill_client**

```
CREATE TABLE `bill_client` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `client_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `client_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `opening_balance` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `conn_charge` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
 `con_date` date NOT NULL,
 `mobile` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
 `pkg_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `conn_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `area_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `managed_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `remarks` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `photo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `company_id` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=165 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

table:**bill_pkg**

```
CREATE TABLE `bill_pkg` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `pkg_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `pkg_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `pkg_rate` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
 `company_id` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `pkg_name` (`pkg_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

table:**bill_rent**

```
CREATE TABLE `bill_rent` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `company_id` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `client_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `due_month` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
 `pay_date` date NOT NULL,
 `amount_due` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `amount_paid` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you are after. Pls provide some sample data, expected results based on the sample data, and actual results produced by your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the client_id doesn't match the `bill_rent` table, `MAX(due_month)` will be `NULL`, so comparing the current month with this will fail. Use `IFNULL(MAX(due_month), '')` so you always get a valid value to compare with.

```
SELECT c.company_id, c.client_id, p.pkg_rate
FROM bill_client c
JOIN bill_pkg p on c.pkg_id=p.pkg_id
WHERE c.status=1 and extract(year_month from curdate())>
 (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(due_month), '')
 FROM bill_rent
 WHERE c.client_id=client_id and c.company_id=company_id)
```

Comment: it's still return only match `client_id` with `bill_rent`, I'm trying for all rows from `bill_client` where `max(due_month) null` and `extract(year_month from curdate())> max(due_month)`

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: BTW, you don't need `GROUP BY` in the subquery, since it's only selecting one client and company.

Comment: yes, `group by` actually nee not here. and it's working now. Thank you so much.